# Jetty SSL config causes 107 / (Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)

Tags: maven, jetty

Jetty 9.0.0.RC0

I'm having problems correctly configuring my jetty service via maven.

Currently I have

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
    <contextHandlers>
        <contextHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
            <war>../dataProvider/target/dataProvider-${project.version}.war</war>
            <contextPath>/dataProvider</contextPath>
        </contextHandler>
    </contextHandlers>
    <webAppConfig>
        <contextPath>/</contextPath>
        <baseResource
                implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.ResourceCollection">
            <resourcesAsCSV>src/main/webapp,src/main/javascript,
                target/closure</resourcesAsCSV>
        </baseResource>
        <defaultsDescriptor>src/main/resources/jetty/webdefault.xml</defaultsDescriptor>
    </webAppConfig>
    <jettyXml>src/main/resources/jetty/jetty.xml</jettyXml>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In my pom and

```xml
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

    <New id="sslContextFactory" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">
        <Set name="KeyStorePath"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />src/test/resources/keystore</Set>
        <Set name="KeyStorePassword">password</Set>
        <Set name="KeyManagerPassword">password</Set>
        <Set name="TrustStorePath"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />src/test/resources/keystore</Set>
        <Set name="TrustStorePassword">password</Set>
    </New>

    <Call name="addConnector">
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
                <Arg name="server"><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
                <Arg name="factories">
                    <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
                        <Item>
                            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory">
                                <Arg name="config"><Ref refid="httpConfig" /></Arg>
                            </New>
                        </Item>
                    </Array>
                </Arg>
                <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" /></Set>
                <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.port" default="8080" /></Set>
                <Set name="idleTimeout">30000</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </Call>

    <Call id="sslConnector" name="addConnector">
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
                <Arg name="server"><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
                <Arg name="factories">
                    <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
                        <Item>
                            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory">
                                <Arg name="next">http/1.1</Arg>
                                <Arg name="sslContextFactory"><Ref refid="sslContextFactory"/></Arg>
                            </New>
                        </Item>
                    </Array>
                </Arg>
                <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" /></Set>
                <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.tls.port" default="8443" /></Set>
                <Set name="idleTimeout">30000</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </Call>
</Configure>
```

In Jetty. I'm guessing its doing something crazy and exposing the https service as http bad request and fail, but i'm not sure why. It's very difficult to debug so i'm curious if anyone else has got it working ?

Comment: I'm not convinced 9 RC1 works. Reverted to 8 where it seems to work with channels.